# UIPanGestureRecognizer interrupting UIPageViewController-- SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` between 4 pages that works perfectly. But recently on the first page, I implemented a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to bring a UIView up and down.

The `UIPageViewController` works super well on its own and so does the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, but not together. The U`IPanGestureRecognizer`interrupts the `UIPageViewController` so I can only swipe up and down and not left to right.

What I aim to do is have the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in place for swiping up and down and the `UIPageViewController` for swiping left and right. Does anyone think they could help me out with that? Any suggestions would be immensely appreciated!!

Cheers,
Theo

P.S. I've tried using a `UISwipeRecognizer` and it works horribly for my use case...

Comment: You may need to have a bit more "control" than a gesture recognizer gives you. Could you use track whether it's a vertical "pan" by using `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`?

Comment: @dfd i actually use a variable i created that tracks velocity along the y-axis. could you elaborate on the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` thinking? Would love to hear more about your idea.

Comment: `UIGestureRecognizer` is could sometimes be considered a "wrapper" above complete touch control. It provides when a touch beings and ends. I was thinking that if you (a) were facing something where `UIPanGestureRecognizer` was interfering with the canned `UIPageViewController` functionality or (b) you weren't correctly tracking Y-axis panning - which you may not be - that *replacing* the pan gesture with this might work. It's a bit more coding - you are basically overwriting all pan gestures - but it might work. (Then agin, maybe not!)

Comment: have you any sample gif to show what happened?